# what exactly does the models.Model argument refer to in models.py?

Tags: python, django

I was looking at

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

which is an example taken from djangobook.com and I was confused about what the models.Model argument.
I get that models is a class with methods such as CharField(), which is being inherited into these classes in order to create table columns...right? But where does the "Model" part of models come in to this? Whats it for? where abouts is it needed?

Any analogies or explanations coming from you would be appreciated, as i have been looking on the internet and still am confused.
Sorry for the ignorantly phrased question.

Thanks!

Comment: `modules` (lower case) is a **module**, while `Models` (upper case) is a **class name** inside that module.  It is likely that `CharField`, `URLField`, etc are *also* classes inside the `models` module.

Comment: Why is the class name "Models" (uppercase) there? whats it used for if the module "models" (lowercase) contains the classes CharField(), etc.

Comment: Q1) Because that's Python's way of [specifying inheritance / defining a *subclass*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).  So in the file you've shown, it's saying that `Publisher` should be a subclass of `Model`, a class defined in the `model` module.  Q2) It's there for a different reason than the `model.CharField()`.  It's there to define the superclass of the `Publisher` class, while `model.CharField()` is there to say that that class's *member* (e.g. `name`, `city`, etc) should be an *instance* of the `CharField` class, which is defined in the model module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get that models is a class with methods such as CharField(), which is being inherited into these classes in order to create table columns...right?

I believe you took a wrong turn at Albuquerque. Lowercase `models` is not a class and `CharField()` is not a method, though it does end up calling a particular method called `__init__()` but we'll get to that in a bit.

First, look at the import statement:

```
from django.db import models
```

Lowercase `models` here is a package, meaning it is a directory containing an `__init__.py` file. Specifically, it is a sub-package of the package `db`, which is itself a sub-package of the `django` package. The Python dotted path parallels the package directory structure.

It is worth noting here that `models` is NOT a module, though it COULD have been. If there were a Python file named `models.py` within the `db` package, then `models` would have been a module. How do we know for sure? By perusing the Django source code, we find that it is a directory, and thus a package. [See the source code here](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/models).

So, packages are directories containing either: other directories (sub-packages) or python files (modules). Class definitions are defined in the modules. Ok, then how is the `Model` class imported from `models` if it is a package and not a module?

This is possible because the `__init__.py` file in the `models` package imports the `Model` class. The `Model` class definition actually lives in the `base` module, yep the `base.py` file within the `models` package.

Now, for the `CharField()`. In Python, class instantiation uses the function notation. When defining your custom `Model` classes, the database fields are created from your model's class attributes. Within the `Book` model, `title` is a class attribute, instantiated from the `CharField` class. When it is instantiated, the `CharField` method `__init__()` is called.

And here is a good place to point out why it is handy to have packages for making imports more convenient. The `CharField` class is defined within the `fields` sub-package of the `models` package, and many of Django's other field classes are defined there as well. Similar to how `__init__.py` in the `models` package imported the `Model` class from the `base` sub-module, it also imports all the fields from the `fields` sub-module.

Since the `models` package takes care of all the sub-imports we'll likely need to use, we can just import that package. Using the `from` style import, we can easily identify all the places in our code where we are using something from that package, since it always has the dot notation `models.Something`.  We don't have to worry about how all that stuff is organized in the package.

For more details, [see the Python documentation on packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).